# Casperjs - is there a way to wait for n seconds?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Just to clarify, I don't want to wait for a condition, simply pause for n seconds. This is the code I have, but id does not work the way I expected it, my suspicion is that "wait" is asynchronous. I want to have the code changed, so that it prints 1, waits for 5 seconds, prints 2, then prints 3. Right now it prints 1, prints 3, then waits for 5 seconds and prints 2.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var fs = require('fs');
var parsedFile = "pfile.txt";

casper.start();

function wait5seconds() {
   casper.wait(5000, function() {
        this.echo('2');
   });
}

casper.then(function() {
  this.echo('1');
  wait5seconds();  
  this.echo('3');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: would you be interested in pure JavaScript delay function?

Answer (score 6):

You should put `casper.wait()` inside a `casper.then()` as follow:

```
casper.start();
casper.then(function(){
    echo('1');
});
casper.then(function(){
    casper.wait(5000, function(){echo('2')});
});
casper.then(function(){
    casper.wait(5000, function(){echo('3')});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to synchronously wait in CasperJS. Any `wait*` that you use should be followed by another step function (`then*` and `wait*` functions). Since `casper.echo(s)` is synchronous, it will be immediately executed.

Of course, you can define your own `thenEcho`:

```
casper.thenEcho = function(s){
    this.then(function(){
        this.echo(s);
    });
};
```

and use it like this:

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.thenEcho('1');
    wait5seconds();  
    this.thenEcho('3');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was actually looking for a wait to wait for a few seconds even that blocks the code execution, came up with a simple JS workaround, which I will post shortly.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using, it blocks the code execution for N seconds.

```
function waitNseconds(n) {
  var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  var time_now = seconds;
  while ((time_now + n) > seconds)
  {
      seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  }
}
```

and then I call it like this:

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.thenEcho('1');
    waitNseconds(5);  
    this.thenEcho('2');
    this.thenEcho('3');
});
```

Which prints 1, waits 5 seconds, prints 2, then prints 3.

Comment: Why do you need to busy-wait? Also, I wonder how you managed to make it work, considering JavaScript is single-threaded. Can you provide a full script?

Comment: I have updated my answer on how I call the function. The reason I needed this - I have something coded in C# with Selenium and PhanomJS drops one of the cookies, which causes my test to fail. Strangely enough, I cannot examine the response headers with Selenum, which would help me read the Set-Cookie headers, parse the cookie I need and then add it to the subsequent calls. I can do this in CasperJS, but in order to code this as quickly as possible and test my code, I needed a way to "pause" the script here and there...I know there's casper.waitForSelector, but there are times I cannot use it.

Comment: To use the while loop force the tread halt and simulate a sort of wait that long for the conditional to become true, seems like a sure way to toast your CPU and also paralyze everything else in your app until the loop is through. Didn't test it though.

Comment: I see, but this doesn't really work in the way you intended in the question, because the `casper.wait(5000` which is based on `setTimeout` will not advance (according to my few tests).